# Receber dados via Ajax no PHP

Tags: php, ajax, react

Estou criando uma aplicação com React, e a parte do back-end com PHP

tenho requisição ajax:

```
pesquisaCliente(e) {

e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url:'http://192.168.0.109/prontaentrega/pesquisaCliente.php',
    contentType:'application/json',
    datType:'json',
    type:'post',
    data:JSON.stringify({nome:this.state.nome}),
    success: function(cli) {

    }.bind(this)
});
```

}

e na parte do PHP:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

include 'conexao.php';

echo $_POST['nome'];

?>
```

**Só que ele não mostra o valor do**  `$_POST['nome]'`

Obs: Não está dando nenhum erro por serem servidores diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está no formato de dados enviado ao servidor. Na requisição ajax você diz que o **contentType** é `application/json`, logo o PHP não irá popular isso nas variáveis `$_POST`, cabe a você ler o que foi postado e executar o `json_decode` nas informações.

Seu arquivo PHP ficaria:

```
<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

    include 'conexao.php';
    $dados = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); // Assim você lê o faz o decode
    echo $dados->nome; // Acessa a propriedade nome do objeto json postado.

?>
```

Comment: ele ta mostrando isso na tela:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Ok. Execute `echo file_get_contents("php://input")`, me diga o que aparece impresso.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, é problema é que o ajax fica esperando um json de retorno, e como eu estava apenas printando a variável no php, ele retornava html. acho que deve ser o react que exige isso.

Comment: Ótimo, fico feliz que tenha detectado o problema.